# Excel time difference

Tags: excel

I have two time:

> 9:29:00 AM (B2)
>
> 6:16:00 PM (C2)

I want to get the hh:mm (hours and minutes) between those two times. I tried the following function:

```
=TEXT(B2-C2,"h:mm")
```

But I get a **#VALUE!** error.

I formatted the two time cells as TIME format (*h:mm:ss am:pm) and result cell also as TIME format (hh:mm)

Comment: Odd. I pasted your 2 values into a blank spreadsheet and the formula worked fine for me. It returned 8:47. EDIT: It must be the order of subtraction. I did the pm minus the am.

Comment: @PowerUser You are absolutely right :)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is that the right way round? Try

`=C2-B2`

You don't need TEXT function

Comment: All you have to do is format C2 and B2 as "time" and your result cell as custom "h:mm". Except you change the day, past 12 PM you must use the date function.

Answer (score 3):

Times in excel are stored as doubles which increment by 1 each day; 0.5 is 12 hours etc.

Best thing to do is use =TEXT(B2-C2,"HH:MM")

This will format B2-C2 (a decimal number) as a time interval.

Of course the contents of B2 and C2 must be numeric; see my VALUE function in the comments.

Comment: I did that and i am still getting #VALUE!

Comment: This will nail it: =TEXT(VALUE("6:16:00 PM")-VALUE("9:29:00 AM"),"HH:MM"). Of course you can replace the literals with your cell references.

Comment: Why TEXT function? Unless there's a specific need to have the answer formatted as text then you don't need it - = C2-B2 should work

Comment: You're correct but C2 and B2 don't contain numeric values; or he wouldn't get #VALUE

Comment: I think C2 and B2 **are** numeric. If C2 is bigger than B2 then the subtraction gives a negative number - the #VALUE! error occurs when TEXT function tries to convert that negative number to a h:mm format, which it can't do.....

Comment: Good point Barry. You're correct. The nearest I can get to with the formatting statement is "[<0]-[M];[H]:MM" which will display negative minutes for the negative case. Can't get it do display -HH:MM though :-(

Answer (score 3):

I believe your #VALUE error is due to your order of subtraction, but I can't be sure without knowing which of those times is B2 and which is C2, and I can't quite comment on your question yet, so an answer it is!

Comment: C2 is the later time and B2 is the start time. Barry got it correct :) Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

As barry houdini mentioned back in 2013, I also ran into the error of subtracting giving a negative number, and excel just throws an error. No other response on the internet gave me good results. Although my method is longer, it always works with times in hh:mm:ss AM/PM. Just change the text format part of the formula for whatever you have. My data was:

11:15:45 PM 1:41:20 AM

I converted it to military time for ease with

```
=TEXT(A2, "hh:mm:ss")
```

Data was now:

23:15:45    01:41:20

I made another column, let's call it C, that just subtracts the second time from the first time,

```
=B2-A2
```

I next used an IF statement on this column, so that if the absolute value of the difference was the same as the number (a positive), I'd use

```
TEXT(B2-A2,"hh:mm:ss")
```

which just subtracts the later time from the earlier time. But...

If the absolute value of the difference was not the same, e.g. error-ville with a lot of hashes ##########, I use:

```
TEXT(24-(A10-B10),"hh:mm:ss")
```

Altogether, we have one more column, which finally spits out the correct hour difference. This column is predicated on columns A, B, and our error-prone difference column C:

```
=IF(C2=ABS(C2),TEXT(B2-A2,"hh:mm:ss"),TEXT(24-(A2-B2),"hh:mm:ss"))
```

this is the most ridiculous thing I have ever done. It's been years and such a simple case, never solved by Excel.